# AngularJS applying jquery after ng-include html template

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using a plugin called jquery masked input. http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
Which is being used to mask `cell phone` and `ssn` as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.mask-ssn').mask('999-99-9999');
    $('.mask-phone').mask("(999) 999-9999");
</script>
```

I have an angular app, which is loading the form via ng-include

```
<div class="myForm" data-ng-include="'/templates/_form.html'"></div>
```

And the simplified contents of _form.html as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input 
        class="form-control mask-phone" 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Cell Phone" 
        name="cell_phone" 
        required 
        data-ng-pattern="user.phone_number_regex"
        data-ng-model="user.formData.cell_phone"/>
    <div class="help-block">...</div>
</div>
```

If I just pasted the _form.html contents in the parent page, all would work fine and the jquery masked input is applied to the html.

Unfortunately, becaues _form.html is being loaded asynchronously now, the jquery masked input plugin doesn't work.

Looking for some advice on the ***best practice / opinionated *** way to apply the mask to the html. Don't know whether to go down the route of injecting $scope into my angular controller then using $scope.apply. Or by creating a directive / or alternative solution?

Comment: You can use grunt-angular-templates to add to $templateCache, instead of loading (_form.html) from http request. Normally, I wrap jQuery calls inside setTimeout, since most can do outside of angular digest, but its just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of ng-include that create a new child scope. You can try to add $parent like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input 
        class="form-control mask-phone" 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Cell Phone" 
        name="cell_phone" 
        required 
        data-ng-pattern="$parent.user.phone_number_regex" //add $parent.
        data-ng-model="$parent.user.formData.cell_phone"/> // the same here.
    <div class="help-block">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but not sure how this solves the problem. The problem is with jQuery masked input plugin. Not with my regex / model.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by wrapping jquery masked input inside a directive

```
app.directive('mask', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

            if (attr.mask)
                elem.mask(attr.mask, { placeholder: attr.maskPlaceholder });
        }
    };
});
```

Then on the html elements for SSN and cell

```
<input class="form-control" data-mask="(999) 999-9999" type="text".../>
<input class="form-control" data-mask="999-99-9999" type="text".../>
```

Any better solutions out there?

Comment: I think this is the best solution, in angularjs app you should wrap any thrid-party (jquery plugin) into directive. It is angular way :)